# ion.rangeSlider update method triggering the change event

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui-slider

I am using ion.rangeSlider plugin in my application, however whenever i update the slider 'from' value, the 'change' event is fired. How can replace the change event with 'finish' event so that it is only fired when the user releases the handle. Here is the snippets

```js
const my_dates = [1560456085813, 1560517726557, 1560518176560, 1561605126457];

$('#updateBtn').on('click', function() {
      updateSlider();
});


$('#seekSlider').ionRangeSlider({
        skin: "big",
        type: "single",
        grid: false,
        min: my_dates[0],
        max: my_dates[3],
        from: 0,
        values: my_dates,
        prettify: convertMillesecondsToDate
        
});
$('#seekSlider').on("change", function () {


        console.log('onChange event fired');

});


function updateSlider(){


     $('#seekSlider').data("ionRangeSlider").update({
     
          from: 2,
     
     });

}

function convertMillesecondsToDate(time_in_milleseconds)
{
        const d = new Date(time_in_milleseconds);

        let dateString = d.toLocaleString('fr-FR'); // 13/06/2019 à 18:27:50
        return dateString;

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ion-rangeslider/2.3.0/css/ion.rangeSlider.min.css"/>

 
<input id="seekSlider" type="text" value="" />
<button id="updateBtn">Update the Slider</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ion-rangeslider/2.3.0/js/ion.rangeSlider.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by using **callbacks**.

There are 4 callbacks. `onStart`, `onChange`, `onFinish`, and `onUpdate`. Each callback will receive data object with the current range sliders state.

What you want is the `onFinish` callback

```
$(".js-range-slider").ionRangeSlider({
    onFinish: function (data) {
        // Called then action is done and mouse is released
        console.log(data.to);
    },
});
```

For more information visit: [ion.rangeSlider](http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/start.html)